# Pairs of integeres for which the arithmetic mean exceeds the geometric mean exactly by $2$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, means

Suppose $0<x<y<2015$ are integers. How many pairs of $x$ and $y$ are there for which the arithmetic   mean  exceeds the geometric mean exactly by $2$?

#### Progress

Obtained the equation $(x+y)=2[(xy)^{1/2}+2]$; how to solve it?

Comment: We have to solve (x+y)=2[(xy)^1/2+2]

Comment: Do you mean $(x+y)\geq 2(\sqrt{xy}+2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let me now write the rest of the answer.For x < y,we have
y=(x^1/2+2)^2

Since y < 2015,we see x can take any value from 1 to 42×42 i.e. all perfect squares between 1 and 2015.

So the desired pairs are(1,9),
(4,16),......,(42×42,1936).Hence the total number of such pairs is 42.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy} + 2$$
$$x+y-2\sqrt{xy} \ge 4$$
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \ge 4$$
$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \ge 2 $ or $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \le -2$

Comment: That much i know ..i also wrote it in a comment..i am facing difficulty in proceeding further

Comment: We have solve it  for equality

Comment: Its now ok ..i can handle it